# Как составить JSON массив и передать его на сервер через AJAX?

Tags: php, html, jquery, json

Впервые столкнулся с такой задачей. Есть 'Корзина', в ней есть список товаров который формируется через php. Задача состоит в том что бы отправить данные по заказанным позициям на сервер через AJAX-запрос.

Я так понимаю нужно сформировать JSON массив и передать его в файл обработчик через AJAX.

В интернете нахожу информацию, но там данные получают из полей input и тд.

Вот кстати сам сайт: https://boosteam.ru/

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php Корзина через БД работаеть? если да тогда получите все записи из базы и потом сделайте его json array

Comment: Да, я уже так и сделал. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Массив с данными необходимо преобразовать в JSON через функцию json_encode().
После чего через этот код, отправить AJAX запрос на сервер для дальнейшей обработки.

```
var string= 'Преобразованная JSON строка';
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'Путь до файла обработчика',
 data: string,
 dataType: 'json'
});
```